# i want to add columns to gridview from data table in page load event:

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, webforms

i try to add columns to gridview from datatable(i fill it from sql database), i debuged it and my grid view has columns but in web side it doesnt show my grid view at all.

```
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
           new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
           {
               DataSource = "HOSEIN-PC",
               InitialCatalog = "project Grid",
               UserID = "sa",
               Password = "fast"
           }.ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            //ستون جدول
            string SqlString = string.Format(@"select *
        from tbl_data ");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlString, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            //GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            //GridView1.DataBind();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                BoundField c = new BoundField();
                //GridView1.Columns.Add(dt.Rows[i]["DATA"].ToString());
                 // it doesnt work in webform so i try boundfield
                c.HeaderText = dt.Rows[i]["DATA"].ToString();
                c.DataField = dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
                GridView1.Columns.Add(c);
            }
            GridView1.DataBind();

            conn.Close();
```

it seems has no problem i have columns in grid view ...
the only problem is when i execute it ,it doesnt show grid view in web side.

Comment: You need to do `GridView1.DataSource = dt;` before `GridView1.DataBind();`

Comment: You don't need to add column manually... if you want to display all the column of datatable, then you just set `AutoGenerateColumns` property of the GridView to false and bound the dataTable to the GridView by doing `GridView1.DataSource = dt; GridView1.DataBind();`

Comment: If you want to display only specific column from the dataTable in GridView then you need to set `AutoGenerateColumns` property to false and use `<asp:BoundField` to define the columns in GridView... and just bound the dataTable to the GridView by doing `GridView1.DataSource = dt; GridView1.DataBind();`

Comment: but i need to add column from data base to grid view ...if i use gridview1.datasource it doesnt work as my wish.@ChetanRanpariya

Comment: oh tnx i wwill try it (autogenerate)@ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 1):

I have tried below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string customColumn = string.Empty;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            customColumn = "AAA";
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

            // Here we add five DataRows.
            table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);


            //Add new column  in gridview if its not set true for autogenerare columns
            //BoundField test = new BoundField();
            //test.DataField = "Country";
            //test.HeaderText = "Country";
            //GridView1.Columns.Add(test);


            //add  new column for your custom variable to datasource
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Country"));


            GridView1.DataSource = table;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                //putting data in column Conditionaly 
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[3].Text)<DateTime.Now)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[4].Text = customColumn;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```